# Авторизация стороннего клиента Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, cors

Добрый день, делаю full rest сервер на Spring. Настроил кросс-доменные запросы:

```
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

Настроил авторизацию:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery(
                        "select login, password, 1 from worker where login=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                        "SELECT worker.login, userrole.role_name, 1 FROM worker " +
                                "join userrole on worker.userrole_id = userrole.id " +
                                "where worker.login=?");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**/creare").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**/delete/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .and().addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .formLogin().successHandler(savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .rememberMe().tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
                .tokenValiditySeconds(1209600);
        http.removeConfigurer(DefaultLoginPageConfigurer.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl db = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        db.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return db;
    }

    @Bean
    public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler auth = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        auth.setTargetUrlParameter("targetUrl");
        return auth;
    }
}
```

Но не могу настроить, чтобы сторонний фронт (клиент) авторизовался.

Comment: Я обошел эту проблему эмуляцией формы на клиенте. JQ может отправлять данные в виде FormData, что устроило Spring.

Answer (score 3):

При "кросдоменных" запросах должен быть включен параметр `withCredentials = true` на клиенте в `JavaScript` ([настраивается в `JQ`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054316/sending-credentials-with-cross-domain-posts))